# Logic Pro sound effects library license

Tags: logic, licensing, license, sound-effects, library

Hi. I'm thinking about using the sound effects that comes with Logic 9, but I can't find the license anywhere, so I don't know what I am allowed to do with them. Does anyone know where it is?

Answer (score 1):

It's all royalty free.

See the document [here](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/logicstudio8.pdf). Look under Section 2 (Permitted License Uses and Restrictions) part C

Comment: assuming you bought logic ;)